# TS Error: Type 'Query<DocumentData>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DocumentReference<DocumentData>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I am trying to run a query against Firestore data. My code is:

```
import { collection, getDoc, query, where } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../../utils/firebaseConfig";

  const getQuery = async () => {
    const userDataRef = collection(db, "userData");
    const q = await query(
      userDataRef ,
      where("mailID", "==", "dashashutosh1999@gmail.com")
    );

    const users = await getDoc(q) //error

  };

  console.log(getQuery());
```

In line `const users = await getDoc(q)`, I'm getting this error:

//error description- `Argument of type 'Query<DocumentData>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DocumentReference<DocumentData>'.`

[image: code screenshot with error]

I tried searching the error but I only got different variant and couldn't find usefull answers to help myself.

I am new to TS and learning by using TS in my projects. I will be really gratefull if you can guide me through this.

Comment: Please form a proper question title and put the error message into the body as text, not as a screenshot.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions: @DanielW.. I had added the error in text  previously. I've now highlighted that. Also can you suggest what type title should I put for future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getDoc()` function is used to fetch a single document using [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentreference). For fetching multiple documents with a [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.query), use `getDocs()`:

```
const users = await getDocs(q);
```

Comment: yeah got it. But I want to fetch a single document only. Also, I saw that using getDocs removes the error.

Comment: @AshutoshDash you can fetch a single document only when you know it's document ID and not value of a field. So unless you know doc ID you'll need to use a query as in my answer.